# Fix branching from wrong branch

Tags: git, git-branch

So the situation is like this. We have a developer branch. From that branch, I have created two feature branches, A and B. Or at least, that's what I thought I had done. It looks like this

```
develop - commitD1, commitD2 ...
 \
  A - commitA1, commitA2
                         \
                          B - commitB1, commitB2 ...
```

What I wanted was this:

```
develop - commitD1, commitD2 ...
|\
| A - commitA1, commitA2
 \
  B - commitB1, commitB2 ...
```

I know what I should have done. I should have checked out develop before creating the branch B. But what should I do to fix this? Fortunately, I have not committed anything to A after I created A. I assume that simplifies things.

But one thing that complicates things is the fact that both are pushed upstream, but none of them are not yet merged.

So how do I fix this problem?

And as a bonus question, how would I have done if I had made commits to A after creating B? That is, if the tree looked like this:

```
develop - commitD1, commitD2 ...
 \
  A - commitA1, commitA2, commitA3, commitA4...
                         \
                          B - commitB1, commitB2 ...
```

Comment: To answer the bonus question, commits `commitA3` and `commitA4` are irrelevant to the situation, they would not have made a difference (regarding B's rebasing needs)

Comment: @kowsky Possibly. I'm investigating it.

Comment: I don't understand the two close votes or the downvote to my answer.  Does anyone care to explain?

Comment: I voted to close since it's a duplicate of the question I linked (and possibly many others). I don't know about the downvote, I think your answer is correct.

Comment: @kowsky Yeah, the question seems similar. There's something that I cannot get to work with it, but I guess I'll post a new question if I fail to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase --onto` here

```
git rebase --onto develop commitA2
```

This will replay the B branch on top of `develop`, assuming this represents the commit in the develop from which you originally had intended to branch B.

A better branch diagram would be:

```
develop: D1 -- D2 -- D3
          \
branchA:   A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- A4
                  \
branchB:           B1 -- B2
```

Using this more exact diagram, the rebase onto command would be:

```
git rebase --onto D1 A2
```

As has been already pointed out in the comments, additional commits to the A branch are irrelevant.  You are rebasing commit `B1` (and the B branch which follows).  What happens on the A branch does not affect the rebase.

Comment: Ok, and I assume that I cannot use the branch names? I have to use specific commits?

Comment: @klutt I think you _can_ use the branch names, if you intend to refer to the HEAD of that branch.  In your case, you want to right things and make it appear that the B branch originated at some commit _earlier_ than the current HEAD.  So in this case, I wouldn't use the branch name, I'd use the commit (maybe you could use `HEAD~2`, but I would probably just use the SHA-1).